# Cargar lista desde archivo txt en C

Tags: c

me dieron la siguiente libreria y tengo que hacer una accion que pase desde un archivo txt que me dieron a una Lista y no entiendo como hacerlo con los tipos que me dan definidos, lo que no comprendo es la ultima estructura si alguien me puede explicar le agradesco.

```
//Registro con informacion de una pelicula
enum generos {Action, Comedy, Adventure, Drama, Horror, SciFi, Fantasy, Animation};
enum colors{Color, BW};
typedef struct{
    char id[15];
    char titulo[100];
    char director[35];
    enum generos genero;
    char likes[10];
    char cantidad_votantes[10];
    char voto_promedio[5];
    char anio[4];
    char costo[15];
    enum colors color;
}Movie;

//LSE de Movie
struct Nodo{
    Movie pelicula;
    struct Nodo *next; 
};

//Puntero al primer elemento de la LSE
typedef struct{
    struct Nodo *head;
}Lista;
```

El txt tiene esta forma:

51052

102 Dalmatians

Kevin Lima

Comedy

372

333

6.7

2000

0

Color

1824

2 Fast 2 Furious

John Singleton

Action

22000

2105

6.6

2003

75000000

Color

**CUALQUIER APORTE ME SIRVE, GRACIAS.**

Answer (score 0):

En la última estructura(Lista), el puntero `struct Nodo *head;` apunta a la primera película. A las siguientes películas, se acceden a través del puntero `struct Nodo *next;`. De esta manera, no es necesario crear un array ya que el "recorrido" entre películas se haría a través de `*next` y, cuando este es 0(NULL), ya no existen más películas.

No sé si me he explicado con claridad, pero es algo así como un Stack.